# Ninject rebinding a method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

Using Ninject i would like to rebind one method to another implementation is that possible ?

I will elaborate, I have this interface with two different implementations:

```cs
public interface IPersonFacade
{
  List<string> GetPeople();
  string GetName();
}

public class PersonFacade:IPersonFacade
{
  //Implement Interface fetching data from a db.
}

public class PersonFacadeStub:IPersonFacade
{
  //Implement Interface with some static data
}
```

I am using the Ninject mvc extension and have my NinjectModule implementation:

```cs
public class ServiceModule:NinjectModule
{   
  public override void Load()
  {
    Bind<IPersonFacade>().To<PersonFacade>();
  }
}
```

So back to my question, is it possible to rebind  the method GetPeople() so it uses the implementation from the PersonFacadeStub but IPersonFacade keeps using the GetName from the PersonFacade ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. NInject like any other DI container manages types, not methods. If you want to use different types for different methods of the same interface pattern **[Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)** may help:

```
public class CompositePersonFacade : IPersonFacade
{
    private readonly IPersonFacade realFacade;
    private readonly IPersonFacade stubFacade;

    public CompositePersonFacade(IPersonFacade realFacade, IPersonFacade stubFacade)
    {
        this.realFacade = realFacade;
        this.stubFacade = stubFacade;
    }

    public List<string> GetPeople()
    {
        return stubFacade.GetPeople();
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return realFacade.GetName();
    }
}
```

and also modify binding:

```
Bind<IPersonFacade>().To<CompositePersonFacade>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("realFacade", 
                  context => context.Kernel.Get<PersonFacade>())
    .WithConstructorArgument("stubFacade", 
                  context => context.Kernel.Get<PersonFacadeStub>());
```

Comment: +1 Nice. @Nizolai Have a look whether Ninject.Extensions.Interception can be of any use (depends on whether you want literally what you're asking for...)